# Data is not being stored in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

[store image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o67wC.png)I am going to store the data into the react-redux-store but it is not getting stored. I don't understand what I am missing...I have given my code below.

i am trying to store the data from the api but it is not working...

**INDEX.JS**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./features/store";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**STORE.JS**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import moviesReducer from "./movies/movieSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: moviesReducer,
});
```

**MOVIE SLICE.JS**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialstate = {
  movies: [],
};

const movieSlice = createSlice({
  name: "movies",
  initialstate,
  reducers: {
    addMovies: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.movies = payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { addMovies } = movieSlice.actions;
// export const getAllMovies = (state) => state.movies.movies;
export default movieSlice.reducer;
```

*COMPONENT*

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import MovieAPI from "../config/MovieAPI";
import { addMovies } from "../features/movies/movieSlice";

const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    const response = await MovieAPI.get(`?apiKey=1234&s=harry&type=movie`);
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch(addMovies(response.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the very first: `createSlice` expecting to recieve object with property named `initialState` instead `initialstate`, notice camelCase naming.

The next one: acording to location and slice name "movies" I may suspect you should define it as: `const initialState = [];`, due to it is "movies slice"  initial state definition itself, otherwise you will have state with something like
`state = {movies: {movies: []}}`.

Also, you may wish to rewrite `addMovies` reducer in something like:

```
    addMovies: (moview_slice_state, { payload }) => {
      console.log("add movies", payload);
      moview_slice_state.push(...payload);
    }
```

where `moview_slice_state` - state of `movies` slice of whole state, e.g. `state.movies`.

By the way, due to [@reduxjs/toolkit use immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) under the hood you may "modify" state **OR** return new state, as Andrej Kirejeŭ propose. But NOT the both of them.

P.S. For the future, feel free to create minimal demo for your question or answer, some thing like [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-71650336-ntupb4) based on your code

Answer (score 0):

return new state:

```
    addMovies: (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state, 
      movies: payload
    }),
```

by the way, how do you know it is not stored. Please, show the code where you use state data to render some component.

Comment: I have added image. You will get to see that ```undefined``` .

Comment: Did you connect your store to the react app through Provider component? Something like this:
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>

Comment: I have added index.js file which contains provider's code...

Comment: how does your App component look like?

Comment: I haven't rendered anything yet coz there is nothing in the redux store so I haven't code to display data.